# Show that $\{w_1,\dots,w_p,v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ is an orthogonal set and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

These series of questions build up on each other i'm stucked on the last one, i'm also not sure if all of these work but I am pretty convinced they do.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an orthogonal basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$ and let $\{v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ be an orthogonal basis for $W^{\perp}$.

> a.) Show that $\{w_1,\dots,w_p,v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ is an orthogonal set.

Since $\{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$ and $\{v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ are orthogonal bases, they are also orthogonal sets, so $w_i\cdot w_j=v_i\cdot v_j=0$ whenever $i\neq j$. By definition, the set $W^{\perp}$ contains all the vectors that are orthogonal to $W$, so $v_i \cdot w_j=0$ for any $i,j$. Thus, $\{w_1,\dots,w_p,v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ is an orthogonal set.

> b.) Show that $\{w_1,\dots,w_p,v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since the space spanned by $ \{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so is the space spanned by $\{v_1,\dots,v_q\}$.

By the Orthogonal Decomposition Theorem, any vector $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a sum of vectors from $\hat{y}\in W$ and $z\in W^{\perp}$, where $\hat{y}$ is a linear combination of vectors in $ \{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$ and $z$ is a linear combination of vectors in $ \{v_1,\dots,v_q\}$.

Hence, $\{w_1,\dots,w_p,v_1,\dots,v_q\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> c.) Show that $\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\perp})=n$

I need a hint here. I am not sure if we are allowed to say something like $\dim(W\cup W^{\perp})=\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\perp})$ because if we are, then cannot we simply show that it equals $n$ since those set of vectors are linearly independent and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ (from (b))?

Comment: a, b seems ok. For c use $\dim (U\cup V)=\dim U + \dim V -\dim(U\cap V)$

Comment: Just being picky here, but I think the correct way of stating the dimension formula is $\dim U\oplus V = \dim U+\dim V - \dim(U\cap V)$, since $\dim$ is a property of vector spaces, not just sets.

Comment: @hjhjhj57, it's just a notation difference. And $U \oplus V$ means $\dim(U\cap V) = 0$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza agreed. Anyway, I still prefer a notation which emphasises the vector space structure rather than the set structure, as you say just $+$ would be the right way. I just wanted to point it out in case anyone found it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your $w_1,...,w_p,v_1,...,v_q$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (linear independence follows from the orthogonality, (a)), and hence due to the well-definedness of the dimension of vector spaces, $n=p+q$. The right expression for your identity would be $\mathbb{R}^n=W\oplus W^{\perp}$ (but your notation $W\coprod W^\perp$ catches some point, since direct sum is a coproduct, which "behaves like" a disjoint union. Perhaps your union notation would mean the smallest subspace containing it?).